# Is a ride of a type you already have just as effective as any?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-2

Let's say I already have a Merry-go-round but it has lost its appeal because it's quite old. If I build a new, separate instance of a Merry-go-round, is it going to be as effective as the very first one when it was built? Or does the game recognize the fact you already have one and makes it less effective?

Pushing the question to the extreme, would it be possible and just as effective to use only a limited number of ride types by cloning them all over the place?

Note: RCT1 and RCT2 share a lot of mechanics. As such RCT1 references backed up with RCT2 experience will be appreciated just the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a test park with duplicated rides to see if one or the other would be affected negatively.

My test consisted of a simple park (using a recreation of the Forest Frontiers scenario from RCT1) where I placed 2 Merry-go-round rides (and then 3) as well as 2 Twist rides. I also added other rides (Pirate Ship and a coaster) as I went. Duplicates were kept at the same price. Some had different Excitement ratings, often thanks to scenery or proximity to some other ride.

As far as I can tell, duplicates do not have any effect beyond being another ride of the same category (low/med/high intensity). Placing, for example, 2 Merry-go-round rides or 1 Merry-go-round and 1 Haunted House should have a similar effect. Ultimately they're both low-intensity rides and this is what's going to affect attendance.

Admittedly, closing one of the clones seemed to redirect guests to the remaining ride. That said, I believe it is more a consequence of guests looking for non-full queues and similar-intensity rides than anything else.

The best proof may be that I managed to have two nicely running Merry-go-round rides next to each other. The newer one was not always the one doing better, interestingly enough.

As an aside, what seemed to impact how many guests went to a ride the most was:

- The ride location in the park. Merry-go-round at the entrance did poorly for years, in spite of a higher Excitement rating from scenery, while the one in the back kept a full queue
- Price, especially for old rides

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find any specific information on the effectiveness of duplicate rides, however, according to a guide from IGN, reconstructing even one part of a ride will re-boost its effectiveness:

> - When nobody wants to go on a ride any more, simply close the ride and 
>     delete one piece of the ride, then replace the piece and open the ride 
>     again. This can be done as many times as you need (you can also do it 
>     when it is raining it will work too). - [Source](http://www.ign.com/faqs/2004/rollercoaster-tycoon-2-hintstips-575834)

In the scenario you talk about, obviously there aren't any parts to it, but the principle is the same; demolishing and then reconstructing the merry-go-round in the same spot should restore guests' desire to ride it.

Comment: Technically, the merry-go-round itself can be considered its only part (excluding the entrance and exit), since you can modify it with the construction tool just as with any other ride.

Comment: I wonder if the entrance and exit are considered part of the ride (that would be cheap renewal!). Good to know for coasters though.

Comment: @leokhorn I'm not certain. Honestly, I doubt it, but I would need to do some testing. Either way, demolishing and replacing it would be cheaper (and more space-efficient) than building a duplicate.

Comment: @Unionhawk The one thing I'm sure of is that you get full refund for a ride (possibly shop) until you open it for the first time. Beyond that you only get part of what you paid. I'm going to assume destroying a ride directly or through the construction menu is the same thing.

Comment: @leokhorn Correct, but at least you get some of your money back, and you can start charging more for the ride again because the AI sees it as "new". Some science on the matter is required though, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Definitive answer from Roller Coaster Tycoon 2's reverse-engineered source code:

A ride's 'value' ("dollar-equivalent of happiness it provides to peeps") is one of the main factors affecting whether or not a peep decides to pay to get on a ride.  (If the ride has no entry fee, peeps don't care about the ride's 'value' at all, and so the ride's age doesn't really matter except for maintenance purposes and "how many guests will come to my park at all" purposes.)

A ride's value gets a big bonus during its first four months after construction, a smaller one during the following eight months, and then starts to decline three more years after that, suddenly losing 25% of its value.  It then loses another 25% of its remaining value after a further two years.  Every couple years after that, the 'value' declines by another 25% of its remaining value.  Each of these 'value' drops results in lower amounts that peeps are willing to pay to go on the ride.

Your question is about duplicated rides.  In addition to the age-related value penalties described above, RCT2 applies a further penalty to the ride value of every ride which is currently duplicated inside your park.  That is, if you have two different Merry-Go-Rounds in your park at the same time, *both* of them will have a 25% penalty applied to their "value", *after* any age-related penalties.  (In effect, having a duplicated ride type makes peeps treat every instance of that ride type as though they were several years older than they are, and therefore 25% less valuable to your guests.)

This means that if you're going to build a new instance of a ride in order to get the "this is a new and exciting ride" bonus again, then you definitely want to destroy the original ride, or else you basically lose the bonus due to the "duplicate ride type" penalty, which coincidentally precisely matches the 'value' penalty you get for a ride being four years old.

If you destroy all but one ride of a particular type, the "duplicate ride" penalty *will* be removed from the ride that remains;  the penalty doesn't "stick" to the ride just because the ride used to be a duplicate.  As soon as there are no duplicates left in the park, the penalty goes away the next time that ride values are recalculated.

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting guide for Roller Coaster Tycoon that has come in handy. According to the guide the Merry-Go-Round that has lost it's appeal can be demolished and replaced which will increase park value. I'm not sure this is the exact answer you are looking for, but this link may come in handy for you: http://www.syntax2000.co.uk/issues/74/rctfaq.qht.txt

Comment: This is asking about the second game, not the first.

Comment: The first game and the second share the same engine.

Comment: @fbueckert As long as it can be proven that RCT1 and RCT2 work the same way on this specific mechanic, RCT1 reference would be fine. Question is: do they work the same?

Comment: Although this is not cited by a specific author according to Wikipedia: Initially, RollerCoaster Tycoon 2 was not entirely popular with fans of the first game, as the game engine and interface were the same as RollerCoaster Tycoon, with minor improvements in graphics (e.g. more images for coaster cars, allowing for smoother animations)

Comment: Well, RCT 2 has the `ATM`, aka the `Cash Machine`, which pretty much lowers the impact of expensive rides. People who don't have enough money (`I can't afford [...]`) will likely visit a Cash Machine to get more money, unless the ride is too expensive (`I'm not paying that much for [...]`);

Comment: While mostly the same, there are differences, for example in the visitor pathfinding (RCT2 made wider paths more functional afaik). This creates doubt.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why was the edit rolled back? Is it bad to quote 8kB of .txt file while leaving a link to the source? I believe people are much more likely to read the answer when they **don't** have to manually download anything.

Comment: http://rct.wikia.com/wiki/RollerCoaster_Tycoon_2 Another source that claims the game is the same engine as it's predecessor. Nothing really new here as far as game functionality. So it makes no sense for the game to change how the flow of 'park value' or 'ride interest' are reflected by guests.

Comment: @Nolonar Neither the initial answer nor the FAQ directly answer the question being asked. A succinct answer with a source is the best kind, but copying the entire source (including extraneous FAQs) is definitely not a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I regularly rebuild rides after so many years as their reliability deteriorates.  This is good to restore popularity and satisfaction by guests and adds park value.  A second copy will draw riders but won't add much to park value as the original did.
I usually save molds of my roller coasters with and without various scenery to facilitate this process.  It makes's for an easy way to rebuild and re advertise a once popular ride.

Thanks, hope this helps.